# ggplot2 Two different font sizes on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, yaxis

I have a series of water quality graphs each made separately using a for loop and then added to together using cowplot's plot_grid().

The labels on the y axis take up a lot of space and I'm trying to make it look less complicated. I'd like to have the main axis title, e.g., temperature, in a larger font size than the units, e.g., (oC). Currently all the labels are in a list that the for loop references. e.g. `axis labels <- list('Temp' = c('Temperature','(\u00B0C)'))`

I have the units and temperature as separate items within the list. Is there a way to do this as part of the y label?
This is what I currently use, but only adds one part with the full label:

```
labs(x= 'Sampling Site', y= axisLabels[[category]][1])
```

And produces something like this (without the celcius):

[image]

#### UPDATE

When I set the font-family to Calibri it makes the spaces quite large. Is there a way to change this?

```
axisLabels <- lapply(axisLabels, function(x) {
  x[[1]] <- paste0("<span style='font-size: 13pt; font-family: Calibri'>", x[[1]])
  x[[2]] <- paste0("<span style='font-size: 10pt;font-family: Calibri'>", x[[2]], "</span>")
  return(x)
})
```

With above code v previously without it

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be the `ggtext` package which via the theme element `ggtext::element_markdown` allows to use a bit of HTML and CSS to style the axis text. In the example below I wrap the units of your text labels inside a `<span>` tag for which I set the font size to 8pt. Note: As we are now in the world of HTML we have to use a `<br>` tag to add a line break:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

axisLabels <- list("Temp" = c("Temperature", "(\u00B0C)"))
# Set font size for units to 6pt
axisLabels <- lapply(axisLabels, function(x) {
  x[[2]] <- paste0("<span style='font-size: 8pt'>", x[[2]], "</span>")
  return(x)
})
category <- "Temp"

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = "Sampling Site", y = paste(axisLabels[[category]], collapse = "<br>")) +
  theme(axis.title.y = ggtext::element_markdown())
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Thankyou. I'm just wondering how would you add in a font type to this code?

Comment: You could set the font family via the CSS `font-family` attribute, e.g. using `paste0("<span style='font-size: 8pt; font-family: mono'>", x[[2]], "</span>")` in the example code will set the font family for the units to the default monospace font.

Comment: I've set it to Calibri. Any idea why the spaces get larger. See my updates for some screenshots.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I just checked on my example code and your code snippet and it works fine for me.